# How to get Javascript ajax response in Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium

I am trying to get `Ajax` response with this method but it returns **`null`**.

Make sure your solutions works before posting an answer.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("example.com")

result = driver.execute_synce_script("""
    function x()
    {
        var data = null 
        $.post('example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{action:"load_links")
        .done(function( response ) 
        {
            data = response
        })

        return data
    }

    return x()
""")

print(result)
```

Comment: I'm not an Ajax/Selenium guru but googling it says that's an asynchronous method, so the result of the call will be available later, when the execution is done. You probably have to listen to an event handler or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "<url>"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
a = soup.find('section', 'wrapper')
```